# Residual standard error of a regression in python

Tags: python, regression

Does anyone know a command or a way to obtain the residual standard error of a regression or standard error of a regression?

I use the following commands to get the coefficients and the R-squared, I would like to learn one command like these for the standard error of the regression:

```html
#For the coefficients:
model = smf.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.params)

#For the R-squared:
model = smf.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.rsquared)
```

I will be really grateful to the person that can help me with this issue.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In particular, "How do I implement this feature?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
Do your research, make your implementation attempt, and post your code as specified in the posting guidelines.

Comment: `print(model.summary())`

Answer (score 3):

For a smf.ols fit

```
# Residual Standard Error of the model
np.sqrt(fitted_model.scale)
```

Comment: I think this is a different measure...The value we get in R using $sigma is different. Using model.resid.std(ddof=X.shape[1]) I got the same form R

Answer (score 2):

To get **Residual Standard Error (RSE)** of a regression model in python's statsmodels library, you can simply apply the standard deviation method with the degree of freedom equal to the number of predictors (p) + 1 as below:

```
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
model.resid.std(ddof=X.shape[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

RSE is an estimate of the standard deviation of error.
You can go like this:

```
import math
import numpy as np


def RSE(y_true, y_predicted):
    """
    - y_true: Actual values
    - y_predicted: Predicted values
    """
    y_true = np.array(y_true)
    y_predicted = np.array(y_predicted)
    RSS = np.sum(np.square(y_true - y_predicted))

    rse = math.sqrt(RSS / (len(y_true) - 2))
    return rse


if __name__ == "__main__":
    y_true = [1, 2, 3]
    y_predicted = [2, 3, 4]
    print(RSE(y_true, y_predicted))
```