# How to implement the Residual Standard Error (RSE) as a metric in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

How can I compute the [Residual Standard Error (RSE)](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/residual-sum-of-squares.asp#:%7E:text=The%20residual%20sum%20of%20squares%20(RSS)%20is%20a%20statistical%20technique,the%20residuals%2C%20or%20error%20term.) as a custom metric in Keras?
The RSE is given by:   sqrt[RSS / (n-2)]
Where the RSS is: sum((y_true -y_pred)**2)
This question refers to a post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333999/residual-standard-error-of-a-regression-in-python). In this post, a user by the name of Swain Subrat Kumar shows the implementation of the Residual Standard Error (RSE). He even provides a minimum working example (MWE) which I believe to be correct.
I repost a shortened version here:

```
def RSE(y_true, y_predicted):
'''
y_true, y_pred: np.array()
'''
    RSS = np.sum(np.square(y_true - y_predicted))
    return math.sqrt(RSS / (len(y_true) - 2))
```

I am trying to translate this code into keras/tensorflow so that I can use it as a metric. So far, I have this:

```
def rse(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    y_true, y_pred: tensor
    '''
    tmp=tf.cast(len(y_true), tf.float32) - tf.constant(2.0)
    RSS = K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) # residual sum of squares
    return K.sqrt(tf.math.divide(RSS, tmp))
```

However, this is not correct. The RSS is ok. Where it all goes wrong is in dividing the RSS by (len(y_true)-2).
How can I fix this? Many thanks in advance.

P.S.: I am having similar problems when trying to create my own variance metric.

Comment: "Where it all goes wrong" What does this mean exactly? Do you get errors?

Comment: No, no errors, with the typecasting. But the results do not appear to be correct.

Comment: No, no errors, with the typecasting. But the results do not appear to be correct. My original code was simply like this: RSS = K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) / ( len(y_true) - 2.0) This gives a type error. So I changed the division then added the typecast and eventually the tf.constant., etc. But it does not appear to be correct. I have similar code for computing the variance which I can compare to how Keras is computing it via K.var(). It does not match so far :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `rse` function as a metric or a loss, it's being applied to batches of data i.e; tensors which are of size `(B, n)` where `B` is the designated batch size and `n` being the number of elements in each vector (assuming each is 1-D). When you apply the division using `len(y_true) - 2`, the `len` function is going to return the number of samples in the batch `B` (the first dimension), where it should be using the value of the second dimension `n`. If you change the `rse` function to use the value of the second dimension in the tensor (`y_true.shape[1]`), the results are correct:

```py
def rse(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    y_true, y_pred: tensor
    '''
    tmp = tf.cast(y_true.shape[1], tf.float32) - tf.constant(2.0)
    RSS = K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) # residual sum of squares
    return K.sqrt(tf.math.divide(RSS, tmp))
```

In a fully reproducible dummy example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np


def rse(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    y_true, y_pred: tensor
    '''
    tmp = tf.cast(y_true.shape[1], tf.float32) - tf.constant(2.0)
    RSS = K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) # residual sum of squares
    return K.sqrt(tf.math.divide(RSS, tmp))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # NOTE: call `expand_dims` to simulate the idea of a batch (i.e a 2D tensor with shape (1, 5))
    # so B = 1, n = 5
    y_true = np.expand_dims(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6], dtype=np.float32), axis=0)
    y_pred = np.expand_dims(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=np.float32), axis=0)
    print(rse(y_true, y_pred))
```

Output is:

```
tf.Tensor(0.57735026, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Which is correct (simply the square root of `1/3`, since we only have 1 error in the example data).

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this answer. :-)  It is exteremely helpful! Even with a MWE!!! Awsome. Unfortunately it has also led to the discovery of other serious problems in my code which I hopefully will be able to solve soon.  :-( I still have some shape errors when changing batch sizes. The idea to simulate the idea of a batch is extremly helpful. Thank you so much!